# Knee injury, feels like there is a knot inside

Tags: running, injury, knee-pain

i injured my knee last friday :( it was during running intervals, i ran on an uneven grass area. i have googled and tried to find similar cases by description but i'm abit overwhelmed and can't pinpoint. i plan to visit the doctor but not anytime soon due to work.

maybe someone else has experienced this, basically:
1. right knee, right side of the knee cap feels like knotted inside
2. if i bend it, that side inside feels like some veins are 'locking' or getting tied in a knot or getting squashed and tight
3. even when leg is straight, there is still pressure on that side
4. the knee looks normal from the outside, no visible lump or anything
5. its the bone, and the pain is only feeling of tightness

will somebody please help me point me to more info? im abit scared seeing some knee injuries in the net, those that says no healing can help, that only surgery can resolve, ie. acl....

Comment: I would go to a doctor as soon as possible. The sooner you go the higher the chances that something can be done.

Comment: Voted to close. We are not a medical advice site. Please get the advice of a doctor or other medical professional.

Comment: @carlos         as everybody else mentioned you should see a doctor and ONLY get a diagnosis from him. Meanwhile, just so that you won't think of the worse about your knee, i had a similar case of knee pressure when bending. In my case, after i saw my Doctor(you should too) he told me i had the [plica syndrome](http://www.eorthopod.com/content/plica-syndrome). Check it out just in case, but again do NOT accept a non medical/professional diagnosis.

Comment: @shadesco thanks for sharing your experience, unfortunately i wont be able to see a doctor soon..

Answer (score 1):

Did you fall during your run? Your description at first made me think of [a crush wound](http://www.mdguidelines.com/crush-wounds), but that usually requires your flesh to have come in sudden contact with a hard surface, such as falling while running. The feelings of 'pressure' you mention point to inflamation, but another thing could be [a DVT](http://www.ehow.com/about_5150693_symptoms-blood-clot-knee.html) (deep vein thrombosis) of a vein in the knee, which sometimes don't have swelling, at least not right away, but you feel pressure.

But to be honest, you really shouldn't wait to see a doctor.

Comment: i did not fall though, when i ran over some uneven ground, i felt something odd, but i still ran anyways, which i regret now.... thanks for sharing your experience, yes i will be seeing a doctor, though not anytime soon as i will be leaving for vacation